# If statement treats the condition as FALSE although the condition prints out as TRUE

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am creating a shiny app, which will show modal only when a user visits the app for the first time. After the first time, modal will not be shown. However, this does not work and modal is shown in every visit.

First I set a session ID as cookies and then tried to put modal inside if statement so that if the session ID is present and equal to what I set, it will not be executed. Although the statement in if condition is `FALSE`, the modal is still shown. In addition, if I write `FALSE` inside if condition manually, it works and doesn't show the modal. I used `textOutput` to show if the condition is `TRUE` or `FALSE` and it shows the opposite of how `if` statement is behaving.

I have also tried to set only `input$jscookie != sessionid` as condition, but it gives `Error in if: argument is of length zero` error although it prints `FALSE` when I use same statement in `textOutput({input$jscookie != sessionid})`.

Below is a reproducible example showing what I'm experiencing. Thank you in advance.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

if (!dir.exists('www/')) {
  dir.create('www')
}

download.file(
  url = 'https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases/download/v2.2.1/js.cookie-2.2.1.min.js',
  destfile = 'www/js.cookie.js'
)

sessionid <- "OQGYIrpOvV3KnOpBSPgOhqGxz2dE5A9IpKhP6Dy2kd7xIQhLjwYzskn9mIhRAVHo29" 

addResourcePath("js", "www")

jsCode <- '
  shinyjs.getcookie = function(params) {
    var cookie = Cookies.get("id");
    if (typeof cookie !== "undefined") {
      Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", cookie);
    } else {
      var cookie = "";
      Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", cookie);
    }
  }
  shinyjs.setcookie = function(params) {
    Cookies.set("id", escape(params), { expires: 0.5 });  
    Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", params);
  }
  shinyjs.rmcookie = function(params) {
    Cookies.remove("id");
    Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", "");
  }
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "js/js.cookie.js")
  ),
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
  textOutput('id'),
  verbatimTextOutput('sometext')
)

server <- function(input, output) {


  observeEvent("", {
    js$getcookie()
    if (is.null(input$jscookie) || input$jscookie != sessionid) {

      showModal(modalDialog(
        "Click close button",
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = tagList(
          actionButton(inputId = "close", label = "Close", icon = icon("close"))
        )
      ))
    }
  })

  observeEvent(input$close,{
    removeModal()
    js$setcookie(sessionid)
  })

  sometext<-reactive({

    is.null(input$jscookie) || input$jscookie != sessionid
  })

  output$id<-renderText({
    paste('session ID:', input$jscookie)
  })

  output$sometext<-renderText({
    sometext()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I may have found the cause of the problem. If I change the if condition to only `input$jscookie != sessionid`, it gives `Error in if: argument is of length zero` error. So it treats `input$jscookie` as `NULL` but `is.null(input$jscookie)` gives `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved it.
Using `input$jscookie` as statement in `observeEvent` and putting `js$getcookie()` outside of `observeEvent` solved the problem.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

if (!dir.exists('www/')) {
  dir.create('www')
}

download.file(
  url = 'https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases/download/v2.2.1/js.cookie-2.2.1.min.js',
  destfile = 'www/js.cookie.js'
)

sessionid <- "OQGYIrpOvV3KnOpBSPgOhqGxz2dE5A9IpKhP6Dy2kd7xIQhLjwYzskn9mIhRAVHo291" 

addResourcePath("js", "www")

jsCode <- '
  shinyjs.getcookie = function(params) {
    var cookie = Cookies.get("id");
    if (typeof cookie !== "undefined") {
      Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", cookie);
    } else {
      var cookie = "";
      Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", cookie);
    }
  }
  shinyjs.setcookie = function(params) {
    Cookies.set("id", escape(params), { expires: 0.5 });  
    Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", params);
  }
  shinyjs.rmcookie = function(params) {
    Cookies.remove("id");
    Shiny.onInputChange("jscookie", "");
  }
'

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "js/js.cookie.js")
  ),
  useShinyjs(),
  extendShinyjs(text = jsCode),
  textOutput('id'),
  verbatimTextOutput('sometext')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  js$getcookie()
  observeEvent(input$jscookie, {
    
    if (is.null(input$jscookie) || input$jscookie != sessionid) {
      
      showModal(modalDialog(
        "Click close button",
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = tagList(
          actionButton(inputId = "close", label = "Close", icon = icon("close"))
        )
      ))
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$close,{
    removeModal()
    js$setcookie(sessionid)
  })
  
  sometext<-reactive({
    
    is.null(input$jscookie) || input$jscookie != sessionid
  })
  
  output$id<-renderText({
    paste('session ID:', input$jscookie)
  })
  
  output$sometext<-renderText({
    sometext()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```